# Chrome suddenly won't play MP3 files in-tab

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mp3

For years it seems I've relied on this feature, to play podcasts, etc, in a chrome tab by opening an mp3 URL.
Suddenly today, every time I try it loads the file then immediately crashes (Aw, Snap).

I've updated Chrome to the newest version and relaunched but it doesn't fix anything. I'm running on OSX 10.10.5 but my system hasn't changed since yesterday when it was working fine.

I'm also getting it on some pages with media e.g. video. The front page of this site crashes every time, after about a second... if I'm very quick I can click on a link to a different section and that loads fine https://pulmanusedcars.co.uk/ Making me think it's the page content somehow...

Comment: Have you tried a new chrome profile? Disabling chrome extensions?

Comment: The only extension I seem to have is AdBlock. I'm now seeing this same issue on other pages, seemingly that involve media. Could it be a Flash issue... or is Flash totally gone these days?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue. I could not find any other working solution but to re-encode all my files. It seems to be a Chrome "feature".

Use VLC to do it. By using VLC's default settings I got a working file with the following properties:

```
General
Complete name                            : demo1.mp3
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 14.6 MiB
Duration                                 : 15 min 55 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 128 kb/s
Writing library                          : LAME3.99.5

Audio
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Format settings                          : Joint stereo / MS Stereo
Duration                                 : 15 min 55 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 38.281 FPS (1152 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 14.6 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : LAME3.99.5
```

In VLC

1. Go to File > Convert / Stream...
2. Drag and drop your file on the window
3. Under "Choose Profile" select "Audio - MP3"
4. Choose a file destination
5. And click the Save button

Try to open your new file with Chrome. It should work.

[image: VLC Convert audio]